# How many iterations of inner models/generic extensions are sufficient?

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Let $M=M_0$ be a ctm of ZF.

1. If $(M_0, \ldots, M_n)$ is a sequence of ctms of ZF, where for all $i,$ either $M_{i+1}$ is an inner model of $M_i$ or a generic extension of $M_i,$ then call $M_n$ an $n$-*model* of $M.$
2. Call $M_n$ an $n'$-*model* of $M$ if we can further demand that $M_1$ is an inner model of $M_0.$
3. Call $M_n$ an $n''$-*model* if we can instead demand that $M_1$ is a generic extension of $M_0.$
4. Let $C_n^M, C_n^{M'}, C_n^{M''}$ respectively denote the sets of $n$-models, $n'$-models, and $n''$-models of $M.$
5. Let $C_{\infty}^M=\bigcup_{n<\omega} C_n^M.$

My intention is that $C_{\infty}^M$ represents the set of $o(M)$-height models which $M$ is capable of "reasoning" about.

> My main question is whether there is some $n$ such that $C_{\infty}^M=C_n^M.$

It's not hard to cook up $M$ such that $C_2^{M'} \not \subset C_2^{M''}$ or $C_2^{M''} \not \subset C_2^{M'},$ so this hierarchy doesn't seem to collapse immediately (if at all), at least in general. It's a priori possible that such $n$ exists for some $M$ and not others; I'm not sure how find an example either way.

If such an $n$ cannot exist, what if we instead ask for something weaker, say $n$ such that $\{\varphi \in \mathcal{L}_{\{\in\}}: \exists N \in C_{\infty}^M(N \models \varphi)\}=\{\varphi \in \mathcal{L}_{\{\in\}}: \exists N \in C_n^M(N \models \varphi)\}?$ It seems like some strengthening of the Inner Model Hypothesis could justify the existence of such an $n.$

Comment: @MonroeEskew Please explain how that makes the hierarchy collapse.

Comment: @MonroeEskew I do, but even if we restrict to set forcing, I don't understand your argument that this collapses.

Comment: @MonroeEskew You seem to have misread the definition I presented. We aren't taking ground models, we're taking generic extensions. The sequence will alternate between smaller and large models, it's not monotonic.

Comment: This terminology is a border wall for anyone interested in answering your question. If not too late, change it. In either case, add more paragraph breaks to your question (and generally when introducing new terminology this should be done in the most readable way, so lots of line breaks, enumeration on the conditions, boldface and/or italic for key terms, etc.)

Comment: Also, since you want to claim that $M$ can reason about all the models in this collection, I assume you mean your inner models to be definable?

Comment: @MihaHabič, could you explain how this goes regarding Usuba's theorem?  Since he only considers choice models in his proof, this sounds like a nontrivial modification. Maybe worth posting as an answer.

Comment: @MihaHabič The case where inner models are definable is closer to what I want, but for this question I'm simplifying things by making $M$ countable and considering arbitrary inner models. Of course, an answer to the definable case would also be appreciated.

Comment: @MonroeEskew Oh no, you are right, I was sloppy about choice, so it is not clear at all.

Comment: If you start from L and each model satisfies ZFC, then it collapses to 1.